# Python, how to alter a method of another class' instance

Tags: python, class

I would like to add some small functionality to a method of another class' instance.
What I tried is listed below. With the same approach it's possible to completely change the method. But I would like to keep a slightly altered version of the original method. Is that possible?

BTW: The classes can not inherit from one another, because I don't necessarily know what class B is.

```
class A:
    def alter_fn(self, obj):
        def wrapper():
            func = getattr(obj, obj.fn_name)
            out = func()
            print('out = ', out)
            return out
        setattr(obj, obj.fn_name, wrapper)
        return

class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.fn_name = 'fn'

    def fn(self):
        return 123


a=A()
b=B()

a.alter_fn(b)
b.fn()
```

For obvious reasons this raises a recursion depth error but I do not know how to avoid that. I also tried `func = copy(getattr(obj, obj.fn_name))`

After altering the method b.fn I would like it to return the value, the unaltered function would return (here 123) but I would also like it to do something else with this output, in this example print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the assignment of `func` above the definition of `wrapper`.

```
...
def alter_fn(self, obj):
    func = getattr(obj, obj.fn_name)
    def wrapper():
        ...
```

This way `getattr` is called only once and `wrapper` can access `func` as a closure variable.

Comment: Yes, now it's obvious. Had a brain-freeze ^^. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take the `func = getattr(obj, obj.fn_name)` out of the `wrapper`function.

```py
class A:
    def alter_fn(self, obj):
        func = getattr(obj, obj.fn_name)
        def wrapper():
            out = func()
            print('out = ', out)
            return out
        setattr(obj, obj.fn_name, wrapper)
        return
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I chose the other answer because he was a little bit faster (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the wrapped function before re-assigning it:

```
def alter_fn(self, obj):
    func = getattr(obj, obj.fn_name)
    def wrapper():
        out = func()
        print('out = ', out)
        return out
    setattr(obj, obj.fn_name, wrapper)
    return
```

This way `func` is assigned only once, when the original function is called. Thus, you can safely call it without calling `wrapper()` again by accident.

Also consider using `functools.wraps()` to keep the docstring and name information of the string the same.